# Join collection with array object field with another collection in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working in MongoDB and getting stuck at one aggregation case. Let me show you my collection.

First collection (data):

```
[
{
"_id": "8e7b3fa0-4230-448c-8f70-1d7300632834",
"data": [
       {
         "animal" : "7d44251a-b308-4deb-875a-33ef0a69fe2b",
         "place": "Chennai"
       },
       {
         "animal" : "fcfdd527-5885-48b0-a91f-03f72f78528f",
         "place": "Kolkata"
       }
    ]
}
]
```

Second collection (Animal):

```
[
 {
   "_id": "7d44251a-b308-4deb-875a-33ef0a69fe2b",
   "name": "Dog"
 },
 {
   "_id": "7d44251a-b308-4deb-875a-33ef0a69fe2b",
   "name": "Cat"
 }
]
```

I'm using this query:

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "animal",
      "localField": "data.animal",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$doc"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "data.animal": "$doc.name",
      "data.place": 1
    }
  }
])
```

and it result me this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "8e7b3fa0-4230-448c-8f70-1d7300632834",
    "data": [
      {
        "animal": "Dog",
        "place": "Chennai"
      },
      {
        "animal": "Dog",
        "place": "Kolkata"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "8e7b3fa0-4230-448c-8f70-1d7300632834",
    "data": [
      {
        "animal": "Cat",
        "place": "Chennai"
      },
      {
        "animal": "Cat",
        "place": "Kolkata"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where I'm expecting like this

```
[
  {
    "_id": "8e7b3fa0-4230-448c-8f70-1d7300632834",
    "data": [
      {
        "animal": "Dog",
        "place": "Chennai"
      },
      {
        "animal": "Cat",
        "place": "Kolkata"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zhTeRfg0pH5)

Also sharing this question in Mongo playgroud. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

1. `$unset` - Deconstruct the `data` array into multiple documents.
2. `$lookup` - Perform join with `animal` collection.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document. For `data.animal` field, get the first value via `$first`.
4. `$group` - Group by `_id`. Push the `data` document into the `data` array.

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "animal",
      "localField": "data.animal",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "doc"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "data.animal": {
        $first: "$doc.name"
      },
      "data.place": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $push: "$data"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K02uWfJM3gd)

---

**Solution 2**

1. `$lookup`
2. `$set` - Set `data` field.

   2.1. `$map` - Iterate the `data` array and returns a new array.

   2.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge current iterated document with `place` field and the document from *2.1.1.1*.

   2.1.1.1. `$first` - Get the first document from the filtered `doc` arrays by matching the ids via `$filter`.
3. `$unset` - Remove `_id` and `animals._id` fields.

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "animal",
      "localField": "data.animal",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "doc"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      data: {
        $map: {
          input: "$data",
          as: "data",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              {
                place: "$$data.place"
              },
              {
                $first: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$doc",
                    cond: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$$this._id",
                        "$$data.animal"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "doc",
      "data._id"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oUbsNu79ICD)

Comment: Solution 2 should probably be preferred. Unwinding and then re-grouping on `_id` is unnecessary and can introduce some extra delays in retrieving the data